# sqlite3 close statement is not working

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm using a C program with sqlite3.
Some times insert works.But sometime ,its not working.
assert(retval == SQLITE3_OK) 
gives error. while debugging I found retval value of sqlite3_step() is error code = 5
which refers to Database file is busy 
Even closing with sqlite3_close() return error code 5.

Any thoughts on how to close the database connection ,even when it's busy?

Comment: Are you using transaction control? Have you tried sending a "COMMIT;"?

Answer (score 0):

You could be in the middle of a transaction. Try checking http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html for explanations on how `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` works. It should return a zero if it is not in auto-commit, meaning there is an open transaction.

Or if you suspect your database might still be working on something, you can use `sqlite3_busy_timeout()` to set a timer. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html